# Bin proportions for plotly stacked histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly-python

Having a dataframe consisting of two columns 'A_scores' and 'B_scores' i want to plot a stacked histogram with not a number of occurences in each bin(by default), but a proportion within the bin

I tried barnorm='fraction' that worked properly for numbers (it's counting proportion within a bin, not all bins), but graph doesn't look like histogram anymore with original y-axis

**This is my initial histogram**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A_scores':[0.551517,0.534198,0.497253,0.543809,0.543504,0.549244,0.543405,0.558572,0.529337,0.529329,0.534366,0.554673,0.527218,0.543405,0.495575,0.548421,0.500000,0.540934,0.522711,0.578787,0.543405,0.529069,0.555789,0.546029,0.537304,0.542614,0.537506,0.565492,0.540440,0.568631,0.540440,0.529329,0.536587,0.538576,0.528558,0.551652,0.541618,0.553818,0.540803,0.532504,0.542149,0.540440,0.543405,0.539693,0.554483,0.528099,0.544920,0.562185,0.531750,0.539293],
                   'B_scores':[0.541878,0.505649,0.523954,0.540440,0.540440,0.545835,0.540440,0.548533,0.529337,0.529329,0.530605,0.511747,0.542734,0.540440,0.532799,0.537804,0.500000,0.540440,0.540144,0.539606,0.540440,0.543018,0.540440,0.530593,0.529009,0.537180,0.530794,0.556053,0.540440,0.529943,0.540440,0.529329,0.540440,0.541723,0.547892,0.537180,0.534612,0.538470,0.545612,0.508890,0.532759,0.540440,0.540440,0.533806,0.533024,0.521673,0.540440,0.532545,0.513191,0.536977]})

fig = px.histogram(df, nbins=10)

fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='black',
                  marker_line_width=0.5) 


fig.show()
```

This shows wrong numbers with **correct** look

```
fig = px.histogram(df, 
                   nbins=10,
                   histnorm='percent'
                   )
```

This shows **correct** numbers with wrong look

```
fig = px.histogram(df, 
                   nbins=10,
                   barnorm='percent'
                   )
```

Comment: it seems there's no such an option in `px`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i'm free to use other modules besides plotly.express, is there a way to resolve the problem with other modules like plotly.graph_objects?